# PHP foreach array returns only the first character

Tags: php

I Have an array in a session that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /storage/ssd3/334/5218334/tmp/php2swaoM
            [1] => Petty cash request form.png
            [2] => ../images/Petty cash request form.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /storage/ssd3/334/5218334/tmp/phpISXPED
            [1] => Business Advance Form.png
            [2] => ../images/Business Advance Form.png
        )
)
```

The problem is that when i loop through the array it is returning only the first character here is my code:

```
  $array = $_SESSION["att_arr"];
  $requestID =  $_SESSION["requestID"];

  foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $filetmp = $value[0];
        $filename = $value[1];
        $filepath = $value[2];

        //move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO attachments (name, location, request_id) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$requestID')";

        if(mysqli_query($dbcon, $insert_sql)){
          echo "done";
        } else{
          echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $insert_sql. " . mysqli_error($dbcon);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: take out the second foreach, change references to `$value` to `$values`

Comment: I come here to answer questions and offer advice, not sure what your agenda is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is looping every item in the inner arrays:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $filetmp = $value[0];
```

In the first loop, for example, `$value` is `/storage/ssd3/334/5218334/tmp/php2swaoM`. When you do `$value[0]`, it'll return the first character.

That's what you did wrong.

I believe you can omit the inner loop if all inner arrays will have a fixed 3 items.